# I got System.StackOverflowException exception while calling WCF services from Win32 Services

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, windows-services

i have win32 services, which are polling database in every 3 seconds throuh WCF services, 
after 20 hours, i got exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in System.dll" in win32 services

can anyone tell me, what's wrong, why is it throwing exception

here is sample code of calling  WCF service from Win32 services

```
            var methodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
            var traceProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            Logger.LogTrace("Start ", methodName, traceProperties);

            Com.Softechww.Services.ContentInfo.EncodingJobs jobs = null;

            try
            {
                jobs = _contentSvc.GetEncodingJobs(encodingSearchCriteria);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError(ex, methodName, traceProperties);
                throw;
            }

            Logger.LogTrace("End", methodName, traceProperties);
            return jobs;
```

Comment: A StackOverflowException occurs when you've run out of stack space due to too many nested function calls.  An obvious check is to see if you're making any recursive calls.

Comment: no, it is just calling WCF method , no recursive calls.

Comment: Post the code for `GetEncodingJobs` - you could have a recursion or infinite loop situation there.